# MSSQL: Going from MD5 to Blowfish

Tags: sql-server, hash, cryptography, md5, blowfish

In an MSSQL environment, I've got a stored procedure which I use to generate hashes. Currently, the stored procedure uses MD5 (with an appropriate security key).

I'm trying to change the stored procedure so that it uses Blowfish instead.

The current line in the stored procedure is:

`select @hashedvalue = convert(nvarchar(32),hashbytes('MD5',@querystring+@hashpassword),2)`

**What's the correct syntax for hashing via Blowfish as opposed to MD5 please?**

I've had a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) but I couldn't work out which algorithm option I should be using...

Thanks!

Comment: Blowfish is not a hashing algorithm per se. Why do you want to use Blowfish? Perhaps what you really want is [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

[HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) does not support Blowfish

You would need to use a CLR function (search for one) or see what [this from Chilkat](https://www.example-code.com/sql/crypt2_blowfish.asp) does

Personally I would use SHA2_512 for simple hashes.
Password hashing is different, you need bcrypt or other iterative hashing solutions.